# Proper object oriented structure for global classes

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns, singleton, audio

What are the pros and cons of using a singleton class for sound management?

I am concerned that it's very anti-OOP in structure and don't want to potentially get caught up going down the wrong path, but what is a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an awkward topic but I'd say that a sound manager style class is a good candidate for a class that should not be initialized.

Similarly, I would find it OK if a keyboard input manager style class was a completely static class.

Some notes for my reasoning:

- You would not expect more than one instance that deals with all sounds.
- It's easily accessible, which is a good thing in this case because sound seems more like an application-level utility rather than something that should only be accessed by certain objects. Making the Player class for a game static for example would be a very poor design choice, because almost no other classes in a game need reference directly to the Player.
- In the context of a game for example, imagine the amount of classes that would need a reference to an instance of a sound manager; enemies, effects, items, the UI, the environment. What a nightmare - having a static sound manager class eliminates this requirement.
- There aren't many cases that I can think of where it makes no sense at all to have access to sounds. A sound can be triggered relevantly by almost anything - the move of the mouse, an explosion effect, the loading of a dialogue, etc. Static classes are bad when they have almost no relevance or use to the majority of the other classes in your application - sound does.

Anyways; that's my point of view to offset the likely opposing answers that will appear here.

Comment: While I agree with virtually everything you said, where does one draw the line? Couldn't I say that about any class I think will be widely used but possibly accessed by something in a way that it shouldn't, thereby prompting me to limit its scope?

Comment: @JohnSmith The most important factor that should define "the line" I think is when you're making something static that **shouldn't** be available to other classes in your program, even if that's just a tiny handful. Playing sounds from anywhere seems far less of a threat than say being able to directly access and modify the player's health from the game's scoring manager for example.

Comment: @MartyWallace I must say I wholeheartedly disagree with just about every statement you made above.  Please read my answer and let's argue :)

Comment: @weltraumpirat I like you, you make me learn things. In reality I just couldn't be bothered explaining the more appropriate implementation like you have :P

Answer (score 0):

They are bad because of the same reasons why globals are bad, some useful reading :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx

A better alternative is to have it as a member of your application class and pass references of it to only modules that need to deal with sound.

Answer (score 0):

"Managers" are usually classes that are very complex in nature, and thus likely violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). To paraphrase Uncle Bob Martin: **Any time you feel yourself tempted to call a class "Manager" of something - that's a code smell.**

In your case, you are dealing with at least three different responsibilities:

1. Loading and storing the sounds.
2. Playing the sounds when needed.
3. Controlling output parameters, such as volume and panning.

Of these, two might be implemented as singletons, but you should always be very careful with this pattern, because [in itself, it violates the SRP](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne), and if used the wrong way, it causes your code to be tightly coupled (instead, you should use the [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern, *possibly* by means of a framework, such as [SwiftSuspenders](http://www.swiftsuspenders.org/), but [not necessarily](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/01/17/dependency-injection-inversion)):

- **Loading and storing** sounds is essentially a strictly data related task, and should thus be handled by the `SoundModel`, of which you only need one instance per application.
- **Controlling** output parameters is something that you probably want to handle in a central place, to be able to change global volume settings, etc.  This *may* be implemented as a singleton, but more likely is a tree-like structure, where a master `SoundController` handles global settings, and several child `SoundControllers` are responsible for more specific contexts, such as UI sound effects, game sounds, music, etc.

**Playing** the sound is something, which will occur in many places, and in many different ways: There may be loops (to which you need to keep references to be able to stop them later), or effect sounds (which are usually short and play only once), or music (where each song is usually played once, but needs subsequent songs to be started automatically, when the end is reached).  For each of those variations (and whichever ones you come up with), you should create a different class, which implements a common `SoundPlayer` interface, e.g. `LoopSoundPlayerImpl`, `SequentialSoundPlayerImpl`, `EFXSoundPlayerImpl`, etc. The interface should be as simple as `play()`,`pause()`, `rewind()` - you can easily exchange those later, and will not have any problems with tightly coupled libraries.

Each `SoundPlayer` can hold a reference to both the master `SoundController` an its content-specific one, as well as - possibly - the `SoundModel`. *These, then can be static references*: Since they are all parts of your own *sound plugin*, they will usually be deployed as a package, and therefore tight coupling won't do much damage here - it is important, though, not to cross the boundary of the plugin: Instantiate everything within your `Main` partition, and pass on the instances to all classes, which need them; only have the `SoundPlayer` interface show up within your game logic, etc.